# SQLCODE in Oracle Equivalent to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

In Oracle,

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE = -31011 THEN
```

How do I convert the above

`IF SQLCODE = -31011 THEN` to Postgres as `SQLCODE = -31011` is not compatible with Postgres

Comment: `ORA-31011` is `XML parsing failed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses "standardized" SQLSTATE codes. You should to find most near code in the table https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html.

You should to prefer named exception if it is available (not available for custom exceptions):

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLSTATE = '22012' THEN
```